# Getting preferences in Java Portlet and displaying using jsf view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, weblogic, portlet

I have a java portlet which has Init-Param name - javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.edit with the value /timesheetEntry.jsp

==timesheetEntry.jsp==

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
<f:view>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="#{timesheetEntryPreferences.new}">
        <c:out value="New Timesheet Entry"></c:out>
    </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <h:form id="timesheetEntryBeanForm">
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" border="1">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText
                            value="Timesheet Entry (#{timesheetEntryPreferences.timesheetEntryId})" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{timesheetEntryPreferences.new}"></h:outputText>
                    <h:outputText value="Timesheet Date:"></h:outputText>
                    <h:inputText id="timesheetDate"
                        value="#{timesheetEntryBean.timesheetDate}" required="true">
                        <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.DateTime" />
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:message for="timesheetDate"></h:message>
                    <h:outputText value="Task Name:"></h:outputText>
                    <h:inputText id="taskName" value="#{timesheetEntryBean.taskName}"
                        required="true"></h:inputText>
                    <h:message for="taskName"></h:message>
                    <h:outputText value="Hours Worked:"></h:outputText>
                    <h:inputText id="hoursWorked"
                        value="#{timesheetEntryBean.hoursWorked}" required="true">
                        <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" maximum="24"></f:validateLongRange>
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:message for="hoursWorked"></h:message>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:commandButton action="#{timesheetEntryController.saveEntry}"
                    value="Submit"></h:commandButton>
            </h:form>
        </c:otherwise>

    </c:choose>
</f:view>
```

==TimesheetEntryPreferences.java==

```
public class TimesheetEntryPreferences {
    private int timesheetEntryId;

    public int getTimesheetEntryId() {
        return timesheetEntryId;
    }

    public void setTimesheetEntryId(int timesheetEntryId) {
        this.timesheetEntryId = timesheetEntryId;
    }

    public TimesheetEntryPreferences() {
        try {
            timesheetEntryId = Integer.parseInt(PreferencesHelper
                    .getPreference("timesheetEntryId", "0"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Timesheet Entry has been set");

            timesheetEntryId = 0;
        }
    }

    public boolean isNew() {
        return timesheetEntryId == 0;
    }
}
```

Note: PreferencesHelper class has static method getPreference() which gets portlet preference.

Now my question is, when portlet is rendered, timesheetEntryPreferences.new must be true and hence

```
<c:out value="New Timesheet Entry"></c:out>
```

must be displayed correct? But its not going into that and always displaying c:otherwise tag (i.e form).

Please let me know what's wrong?

Comment: I don't know what's your `PreferencesHelper.getPreference("timesheetEntryId", "0")` call is returning, but it looks like is a different value than "0". Please do some debugging for this.

Comment: Well I printed its value in TimesheetEntryPreferences.java right after its returned from PreferencesHelper... System.out.println("Value of timesheetEntryId:" + timesheetEntryId); And its outputting, Value of timesheetEntryId:0